# xml to json conversion - Additional square bracket for [[]] for lineitems and with a line item

Tags: json, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

we have 1 or more than 1 lineitems.

Need square bracket even for single line item or multiple lineitem for "vpoItemList" :[ and child lineitem  "vpoItemCsList" : [

Additional square bracket for single or multiple line item for (vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList & vpoShipDtlCsGroupList).

The 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList' should have square bracket for each lineitem as per the below expected json file. "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList": [[{....}],[{...}]]

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ns0:PO_Message
    xmlns:ns0="http://test.com/Test">
    <domainId>MAIL</domainId>
    <hubDomainId>MAIL</hubDomainId>
    <isForReference>false</isForReference>
    <status>releasedToVendor</status>
    <docStatus>active</docStatus>
    <editingStatus>confirmed</editingStatus>
    <vpoNo>4512826888</vpoNo>
    <vpoDate>2021-02-23</vpoDate>
    <instructions>METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number</instructions>
    <businessRefNo>4512826118</businessRefNo>
    <totalItems>1</totalItems>
    <totalQty>160</totalQty>
    <season>
        <code>F21</code>
    </season>
    <custId>
        <refNo>C000001</refNo>
    </custId>
    <vendorId>
        <vendorCode>41843</vendorCode>
    </vendorId>
    <headerFactory>
        <refNo>F000026</refNo>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
    </headerFactory>
    <vpoItemList>
        <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        <itemName>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemName>
        <customerItemNo>19979</customerItemNo>
        <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        <itemDesc>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemDesc>
        <shipQty>160</shipQty>
        <planedQty>160</planedQty>
        <qtyPerExportCarton>160</qtyPerExportCarton>
        <qtyPerInnerCarton>160</qtyPerInnerCarton>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
        <refNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <uom>
            <code>PCS</code>
        </uom>
        <brand>
            <code>MAIL Co-op</code>
        </brand>
        <itemId>
            <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        </itemId>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
        <vpoItemCsList>
            <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
            <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
            <vpoItemColorId>
                <refNo>METAL</refNo>
                <shortName>METAL</shortName>
            </vpoItemColorId>
            <vpoItemSizeId>
                <refNo>No Size</refNo>
                <displayName>No Size</displayName>
            </vpoItemSizeId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
            <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        </vpoItemCsList>
        <factId>
            <factCode>900088</factCode>
        </factId>
    </vpoItemList>
    <vpoItemList>
        <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
        <itemName>Flash 22 Member Exclusive</itemName>
        <customerItemNo>22825</customerItemNo>
        <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        <itemDesc>Flash 22 Member Exclusive</itemDesc>
        <shipQty>160</shipQty>
        <planedQty>160</planedQty>
        <qtyPerExportCarton>160</qtyPerExportCarton>
        <qtyPerInnerCarton>160</qtyPerInnerCarton>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
        <refNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</refNo>
        <uom>
            <code>PCS</code>
        </uom>
        <brand>
            <code>MAIL Co-op</code>
        </brand>
        <itemId>
            <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
        </itemId>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
        <vpoItemCsList>
            <itemLotNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1</itemLotNo>
            <vpoItemColorRef>UNDYED</vpoItemColorRef>
            <vpoItemColorId>
                <refNo>UNDYED</refNo>
                <shortName>UNDYED</shortName>
            </vpoItemColorId>
            <vpoItemSizeRef>One Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
            <vpoItemSizeId>
                <refNo>One Size</refNo>
                <displayName>One Size</displayName>
                <sizeUniqueKey>SIZE1</sizeUniqueKey>
            </vpoItemSizeId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
            <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        </vpoItemCsList>
        <factId>
            <factCode>900088</factCode>
        </factId>
    </vpoItemList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
        <qty>160</qty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoShipId>
            <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
            <originalShipmentDate>2021-08-17</originalShipmentDate>
            <shipmentDate>2021-08-23</shipmentDate>
            <originalInDcDate>2021-09-15</originalInDcDate>
            <inDcDate>2021-09-15</inDcDate>
            <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
            <shipMode>
                <code>3</code>
            </shipMode>
            <finalDestination>
                <code>0001</code>
            </finalDestination>
            <portOfLoading>
                <code>DLC Dalian</code>
            </portOfLoading>
        </vpoShipId>
        <shipMode>
            <code>3</code>
        </shipMode>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
    </vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
        <qty>630</qty>
        <refNo>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoShipId>
            <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
            <originalShipmentDate>2021-08-17</originalShipmentDate>
            <shipmentDate>2021-08-23</shipmentDate>
            <originalInDcDate>2021-09-15</originalInDcDate>
            <inDcDate>2021-09-15</inDcDate>
            <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
            <shipMode>
                <code>3</code>
            </shipMode>
            <finalDestination>
                <code>0001</code>
            </finalDestination>
            <portOfLoading>
                <code>DLC Dalian</code>
            </portOfLoading>
        </vpoShipId>
        <shipMode>
            <code>3</code>
        </shipMode>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
    </vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
        <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
        <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
        <colorSizeQty>160</colorSizeQty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1/METAL/No Size</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
        <vpoItemSizeRef>No Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
        <vpoShipDtlColorRef>1</vpoShipDtlColorRef>
        <vpoShipDtlSizeRef>1</vpoShipDtlSizeRef>
    </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
        <itemLotNo>22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1</itemLotNo>
        <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
        <colorSizeQty>630</colorSizeQty>
        <refNo>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1/UNDYED/One Size</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoItemRef>
        <itemSizeId>035ae556951b413588cb935fe8abe89e</itemSizeId>
        <itemColorId>92bdbbe775cd470dbfaba3b58597f0a8</itemColorId>
        <itemColor />
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>22825-2021-0001-43095</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoItemColorRef>UNDYED</vpoItemColorRef>
        <vpoItemSizeRef>One Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
        <vpoShipDtlColorRef>1</vpoShipDtlColorRef>
        <vpoShipDtlSizeRef>1</vpoShipDtlSizeRef>
    </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
</ns0:PO_Message>
```

XsltCode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <array>
          <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </map>          
        </array>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

ExpectedJsonfile:

```
 {
    "domainId": "MAIL",
    "hubDomainId": "MAIL",
    "isForReference": false,
    "status": "releasedToVendor",
    "docStatus": "active",
    "editingStatus": "confirmed",
    "vpoNo": "4512826888",
    "vpoDate": "2021-02-23",
        "instructions": "METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number",
    "businessRefNo": "4512826118",
    "totalItems": 1,
    "totalQty": 160,
    "season": {
        "code": "F21"
    },
    "custId": {
        "refNo": "C000001"
    },
    "vendorId": {
        "vendorCode": "41843"
    },
    "headerFactory": {
        "refNo": "F000026",
        "factCode": "900088"
    },
    "vpoItemList": [
        {
            "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843",
            "itemName": "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
            "customerItemNo": "19979",
            "lotNo": 1,
            "itemDesc": "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
                        "shipQty": 160,
                        "planedQty": 160,
                        "qtyPerExportCarton": 160,
            "qtyPerInnerCarton": 160,
            "factCode": "900088",
            "refNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
            "uom": {
                "code": "PCS"
            },
            "brand": {
                "code": "MAIL Co-op"
            },
            "itemId": {
                "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
            },
            "portOfLoading": {
                "code": "DLC Dalian"
            },
            "vpoItemCsList": [
                {
                    "itemLotNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
                    "vpoItemColorRef": "METAL",
                    "vpoItemColorId": {
                        "refNo": "METAL",
                        "shortName": "METAL"
                    },
                    "vpoItemSizeId": {
                        "refNo": "No Size",
                        "displayName": "No Size"
                    },
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    },
                    "lotNo": 1
                }
            ],
            "factId": {
                "factCode": "900088"
            }
        },
        {
            "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095",
            "itemName": "Flash 22 Member Exclusive",
            "customerItemNo": "22825",
            "lotNo": 1,
            "itemDesc": "Flash 22 Member Exclusive",
                        "shipQty": 160,
                        "planedQty": 160,
                        "qtyPerExportCarton": 160,
            "qtyPerInnerCarton": 160,
            "factCode": "900088",
            "refNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
            "uom": {
                "code": "PCS"
            },
            "brand": {
                "code": "MAIL Co-op"
            },
            "itemId": {
                "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
            },
            "portOfLoading": {
                "code": "DLC Dalian"
            },
            "vpoItemCsList": [
                                {
                    "itemLotNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1",
                    "vpoItemColorRef": "UNDYED",
                    "vpoItemColorId": {
                        "refNo": "UNDYED",
                        "shortName": "UNDYED"
                        },
                    "vpoItemSizeRef": "One Size",
                    "vpoItemSizeId": {
                        "refNo": "One Size",
                        "displayName": "One Size",
                        "sizeUniqueKey": "SIZE1"
                        },
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                        },
                    "lotNo": 1
                    
                }
            ],
            "factId": {
                "factCode": "900088"
            }
        }       
    ],
    "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList": [
        [
            {
                "qty": 160,
                "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemRef": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001",
                "vpoShipId": {
                    "shipmentNo": "00001",
                    "originalShipmentDate": "2021-08-17",
                    "shipmentDate": "2021-08-23",
                    "originalInDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "inDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                    "shipMode": {
                        "code": "3"
                    },
                    "finalDestination": {
                            "code": "0001"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                        "code": "DLC Dalian"
                    }
                },
                "shipMode": {
                    "code": "3"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                            "code": "DLC Dalian"
                }
            },
                  {
                "qty": 630,
                "refNo": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemRef": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001",
                "vpoShipId": {
                    "shipmentNo": "00001",
                    "originalShipmentDate": "2021-08-17",
                    "shipmentDate": "2021-08-23",
                    "originalInDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "inDcDate": "2021-09-15",
                    "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                    "shipMode": {
                        "code": "3"
                    },
                    "finalDestination": {
                            "code": "0001"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                        "code": "DLC Dalian"
                    }
                },
                "shipMode": {
                    "code": "3"
                            },
                            "portOfLoading": {
                            "code": "DLC Dalian"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList": [
        [
            {
                "itemLotNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
                "shipmentNo": "00001",
                "colorSizeQty": 160,
                "refNo": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1/METAL/No Size",
                "vpoItemRef": "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "19979-2021-0002-41843"
                    }
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
                "vpoItemColorRef": "METAL",
                "vpoItemSizeRef": "No Size",
                "vpoShipDtlColorRef": "1",
                "vpoShipDtlSizeRef": "1"
            }
        ],
        [
                        {
                "itemLotNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095-Lot1",
                "shipmentNo": "00001",
                "colorSizeQty": 630,
                "refNo": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1/UNDYED/One Size",
                "vpoItemRef": "22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "itemSizeId": "035ae556951b413588cb935fe8abe89e",
                "itemColorId": "92bdbbe775cd470dbfaba3b58597f0a8",
                "itemColor": {},
                "vpoItemId": {
                    "itemId": {
                        "itemNo": "22825-2021-0001-43095"
                         }
                    
                },
                "vpoShipRef": "00001/22825-2021-0001-43095-1",
                "vpoItemColorRef": "UNDYED",
                "vpoItemSizeRef": "One Size",
                "vpoShipDtlColorRef": "1",
                "vpoShipDtlSizeRef": "1"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An adaption of the code needs to check for those elements in the grouping code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
                        <array>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                        </array>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:otherwise>                      
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The additional square [[]] is not working for single lineitem. when we have single items like 'vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList' & 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList'. Please remove the extra lineitem for 'vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList' & 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList'.   from the given xml and test. Need square bracket for each and every lineitem of 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList'. It was given in the json expected file

Comment: Tried with the template to get the square bracket for 'vpoItemCsList' which is a child element in "vpoItemList" but didnt get the square bracket  <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList | self::vpoItemCsList">

Comment: @raviteja, please understand that code samples on StackOverflow should help to solve a single issue you couldn't get working on your own and you should then adapt to your needs. So try try to understand the various answers you have received by now and then to adapt them yourself to your more complex requirements.

Comment: @Martin-Thanks for the support....Trying to get the square bracket for with the templates <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" | self::vpoItemList">  & <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" | self::vpoItemList/vpoItemCsList"> only am getting the square bracket for vpoItemList not for vpoItemCsList. The single lineitems having arrays when i removed the grouping but for multiple lineitems.....please share any template for single lineitems to get the arrays[].

Comment: we are close by to achieve the expected output only need is to arrays for single lineitems and multipel lineitems. Request to modify the the template to get the single and multipel lineitems with square brackets.

Comment: we were able to get the expected json file for single line items. The template we used in is               <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::vpoItemList or self::vpoItemCsList or self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList or self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">. But the last lineitems 'vpoShipDtlCsGroupList'[[..][..]] should have array for eachlineitem. Any suggestions ?